# Get top(n) nodes for given node by relationship type

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to retrieve a list of persons a given node communicates most frequently with including the relationship type. The below query returns the relationship type and the total count of the relationship.

```
START n=node(3) 
MATCH n-[r]-() 
RETURN type(r), count(*)
```

result looks something like this:

```
Type:   Count:
SENT    1000
TO      345
CC      23
```

I would like to extends this query to return the following result

```
Name:    Type:    Count:
John     TO       55
Mike     TO       40
```

Is this even possible? If so what do I need to change/add to my query in order to get my desired result?

Kind regards,
Martijn

Answer (score 2):

Seems it wasn't that hard...

the below query return my desired result

```
START n=node(3) 
MATCH (n)<-[r]-(x)
WITH x
MATCH (x)-[r]->(y)
RETURN y.name AS name, y.address AS address, type(r) AS relationship, count(*) AS counter
ORDER BY counter DESC LIMIT 10
```

Hope it will help someone else!